# Is it sin to pluck or broke flowers from plants after evening?

Tags: belief, sin

there is popular belief particular in Gujarat that it is sin to pluck or broke flowers from plants or tree  after evening.

My Question really  Is it sin to pluck or broke flowers from plants or tree  after evening ? or it's only a belief

Comment: I have given an answer below, you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no concept of 'sin' in the framework of Hindu traditions.
There is pāpa or adharma, but that's not equal to 'sin'.

Vīramitrodaya Pūjāprakāśa (pg.70) quotes Dakṣa

> samitpuṣpakuśādīnāṁ sa kālaḥ parikīrtitaḥ // (Dakṣasmr̥ti 1.32a)

As per this śloka, plucking flowers, leaves, etc. should be done in 2nd bhāga of the day(dvitīye ceva bhāge- Dakṣasmr̥ti 1.29b), that would be 'saṅgava'. This aligns with the traditional practice, as per which, we pluck flowers after the prātaḥ snāna, usually.

Anuṣṭhānaprakāśa (pg. 12) quotes Matsyasūkta,

> snātvā madhyāhnsamaye na cchindyātkusumaṁ naraḥ / 
> tatpuṣyārcane devi raurave paripacyate //

This makes it pretty clear one shouldn't pluck flowers after madhyāhn snāna, because upon doing pūjā with those flowers as offering, one attains gati in raurava naraka.

Vīramitrodaya Pūjāprakāśa (pg. 68) quotes Hārīta 
(as per Anuṣṭhāna prakāśa pg. 12, the first śloka is from Laghuhārītaḥ)

> snānaṁ kr̥tvātu ye kecit puṣpaṁ gr̥haṇanti vai dvijāḥ / 
> devatāstanna gr̥haṇanti bhasmībhavati kāṣṭhavat // 
> snānamatra prātaḥ snānātiriktaṁ, prātaḥ snānottaraṁ puṣpāharaṇādividhānāt /

As per these śloka, one shouldn't pluck flowers after snāna because devatās don't accept that as an offering in pūjā. This doesn't mean that one should pluck flowers before snāna. The 'snāna' in the first śloka (first 2 lines) is referring to madhyāhn snāna, not prātaḥ snāna. This is clarified by the last śloka in the quote and also said that one should pluck flowers after prātaḥ snāna.

Therefore, it should be clear now that what you called a popular belief has śāstra pramāṇa (as well as sadācāra of śiṣṭas) to its support. So, it's not mere hearsay but actually adhārmika/pāpa to pluck flowers for pūjā, after madhyāhn snāna. This rules out evening and night too.  
And it's also pāpa to pluck flowers without having snāna before.

***References***

- Devapūjā-prakaraṇa:  https://shivloti.tripod.com/upasana/methods%20of%20worship%20b%202.pdf
- Vīramitrodayaḥ Pūjāprakāśaḥ (Vol.4): https://archive.org/details/ViraMitrodayaPujaPrakashVol41987ReprintChowkhambaSanskritSeries/mode/2up?view=theater
- Anuṣṭhānaprakāśaḥ (Part 1): https://archive.org/details/AnushthanaPrakasaMahanibandhaChaturthilalSarma1934Khemraj/Anushthana%20Prakasa%20%28Mahanibandha%29%20-%20Chaturthilal%20Sarma%201934%20%28Khemraj%29_Part1/mode/2up?view=theater