# Is cutting branches or leaves of plants prohibited after sunset?

Tags: scripture, plants

This question is not about special plants like Tulasi.

I am asking about other plants that may not be as important as Tulasi.

Is it allowed to pluck leaves or cut branches from plants or trees after sunset?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8908/is-it-sin-to-pluck-or-broke-flowers-from-plants-after-evening

Comment: I have given an answer w.r.t flowers https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56753/24460
You can check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Not only cutting branches or leaves, even going near to trees at night is not permitted.

> **Manusmriti 4:73**:- Let him not enter a walled village or house except by the gate, and **by night let him keep away from trees.**

Comment: The verse doesn't say it is prohibited but it say it is not recommended.

Comment: Security reason? Danger of armed attackers hiding on trees taking cover of darkness ? A walled village maybe also a fortified trap.